# Access VBA Version Check Front End

Tags: vba, ms-access, frontend

I am going to be splitting an Access database into a Front End (everything except tables) and Back End (tables only). I will put the Back End file on a network share and distribute the Front End file to each user so they have their own copy. When it comes time to update the Front End I would like a message to appear when they open their version to indicate it is out of date and hopefully prevent any access.

I was thinking of creating a table on the Front End and on the Back End that stores the version number of the Front End (e.g. 1.02). Then when I update the version of the Front End in the table on the Back End the old Front Ends will pop up a message and stop working.

So I created the tables and created a query to show the Front End version number in both the Front End version table and the Back End version table. Now how do I auto run this query and pop up a message and stop access when the version numbers are different???

Is there a better way???

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In theory, you could have the Access database automatically overwrite itself instead (using some sort of launcher), that way it would always be the most up-to-date version. But if you're dead set on version checks, someone may have a better idea how to deal with that.

Comment: It is a great approach. In your main starutp code (or form), simply pull each value, and check the version numbers. Pop up a message that the application needs to be upgraded (or better yet, ASK the user if they want to upgrade). You can then simply shell out to a bat file that copies the new FE - and do a application.Quit to exist access (since you can't overwrite the front end while you are running it).  I usually run a vbs script, and in that script have one msgbox like "about to upgrade, yes/no" - as this prompt gives access time to exit and shutdown.

Comment: you can create a small hidden form while opening the main form and than check that the version and if it is different than make that hidden form to visible and let your message display on it and you can also shutdown the access form when the fornd end is not a new version. you look here how to force shutdown all other access fornd end on the network . [link](http://www.peterssoftware.com/fsd.htm)

Answer (score 1):

It is much simpler to use a shortcut to launch the application pulling a fresh copy each time from a networked distribution folder. On a modern network it takes a second or so, and the user will always have an updated and non-bloated copy.

All you need is a script. I wrote up once a full article on how to handle this even in a Citrix environment:

[Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

The script establishes two copies of the frontend. That you may not need, thus you can reduce the script somewhat:

```
Option Explicit

' Launch script for PPT test/development/operation.
' Version 1.3.0
' 2013-09-15
' Cactus Data. Gustav Brock

Const DESKTOP = &H10
Const LOCALAPPDATA = &H1C

Dim objFSO
Dim objAppShell
Dim objDesktopFolder
Dim objLocalAppDataFolder
Dim objLocalFolder
Dim objRemoteFolder

Dim strLocalFolder
Dim strRemoteFolder
Dim strDesktopFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataDsgFolder
Dim strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder
Dim strDsgSubfolder
Dim strPptSubfolder
Dim strPptAppSubfolder
Dim strPptNcSuffix
Dim strAppName
Dim strAppSuffix
Dim strShortcutName
Dim strAppLocalPath
Dim strAppLocalBackPath
Dim strAppRemotePath
Dim strShortcutLocalPath
Dim strShortcutRemotePath
Dim strRegPath
Dim strRegKey
Dim strRegValue
Dim booNoColour

Dim varValue


' Adjustable parameters.
strDsgSubfolder = "DSG"
strPptSubfolder = "PPT"
strPPtNcSuffix = "NC"
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Uncomment one folder name only:
'strPptAppSubfolder = "Development"
strPptAppSubfolder = "Operations"
'strPptAppSubfolder = "Test"
' ---------------------------------
' Indicate if the script is for the normal version (0) or the no-colour version (1):
booNoColour = 0
' ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
strRemoteFolder = "K:\_Shared\Sales Planning\Environments\" & strPptAppSubfolder
If booNoColour = 1 Then
  strAppSuffix = strPptNcSuffix
Else
  strAppSuffix = ""
End If
strAppName = "SalesPlanningTool" & strAppSuffix & ".accdb"
If strPptAppSubfolder = "Operations" Then
  If strAppSuffix = "" Then
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT.lnk"
  Else
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strAppSuffix & ".lnk"
  End If
Else
  If strAppSuffix = "" Then
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strPptAppSubfolder & ".lnk"
  Else
    strShortcutName = "RunPPT " & strAppSuffix & " " & strPptAppSubfolder & ".lnk"
  End If
End If

' Enable simple error handling.
On Error Resume Next

' Find user's Desktop and AppData\Local folder.
Set objAppShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objDesktopFolder = objAppShell.Namespace(DESKTOP)
strDesktopFolder = objDesktopFolder.Self.Path
Set objLocalAppDataFolder = objAppShell.Namespace(LOCALAPPDATA)
strLocalAppDataFolder = objLocalAppDataFolder.Self.Path

' Dynamic parameters.
strLocalAppDataDsgFolder = strLocalAppDataFolder & "\" & strDsgSubfolder
strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder = strLocalAppDataDsgFolder & "\" & strPptSubfolder
strLocalFolder = strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder & "\" & strPptAppSubfolder
strAppLocalPath = strLocalFolder & "\" & strAppName
strShortcutLocalPath = strDesktopFolder & "\" & strShortcutName

' Permanent parameters.
strAppRemotePath = strRemoteFolder & "\" & strAppName
strShortcutRemotePath = strRemoteFolder & "\" & strShortcutName

' Create the File System Object.
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strRemoteFolder) Then
  Call ErrorHandler("No access to " & strRemoteFolder & ".")
Else
  Set objRemoteFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strRemoteFolder)
  ' If local folder does not exist, create the folder.
  If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder) Then
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalAppDataDsgFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalAppDataDsgFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalAppDataDsgFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalAppDataDsgPPtFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalAppDataDsgPptFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
    If Not objFSO.FolderExists(strLocalFolder) Then
      Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strLocalFolder)
      If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
        Call ErrorHandler("Folder " & strLocalFolder & " could not be created.")
      End If
    End If
  End If
  Set objLocalFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strLocalFolder)
End If

If Not objFSO.FileExists(strAppRemotePath) Then
  Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppRemotePath & vbCrLF & "could not be found.")
Else
  ' Close a running PPT.
  Call KillTask("PPT")
  ' Wait while TaskKill is running twice to close the instance(s) of PPT and PPT Background.
  Call AwaitProcess("taskkill.exe")
  Call KillTask("PPT Background")
  ' Wait while TaskKill is running twice to close the instance(s) of PPT and PPT Background.
  Call AwaitProcess("taskkill.exe")

  ' Copy app to local folder.
  If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
    objFSO.DeleteFile(strAppLocalPath)
    If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
      Call ErrorHandler("The application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppName & vbCrLF & "can not be refreshed/updated. It may be in use.")
    End If
  End If
  If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
    Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppLocalPath & vbCrLF & "could not be replaced.")    
  Else
    objFSO.CopyFile strAppRemotePath, strAppLocalPath
    If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
      Call ErrorHandler("Application could not be copied to " & strLocalFolder & ".")
    End If
    ' Create copy for PPT Background.
    strAppLocalBackPath = Replace(Replace(strAppLocalPath, ".accdb", ".accbg"), "SalesPlanningTool", "SalesPlanningToolBack")
    objFSO.CopyFile strAppLocalPath, strAppLocalBackPath
    If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
      Call ErrorHandler("Background application could not be copied to " & strLocalFolder & ".")
    End If
  End If

  ' Copy shortcut.
  objFSO.CopyFile strShortcutRemotePath, strShortcutLocalPath
  If Not Err.Number = vbEmpty Then
    Call ErrorHandler("Shortcut could not be copied to your Desktop.")
  End If
End If

' Write Registry entries for Access security.
strRegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Access\Security\"
strRegValue = "VBAWarnings"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = 1
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue,"REG_DWORD")

strRegKey = strRegKey & "Trusted Locations\LocationLocalAppData\"
strRegValue = "AllowSubfolders"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = 1
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_DWORD")

strRegValue = "Date"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = Now
varValue = FormatDateTime(varValue, vbShortDate) & " " & FormatDateTime(varValue, vbShortTime)
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

strRegValue = "Description"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = "Local AppData"
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

strRegValue = "Path"
strRegPath = strRegKey & strRegValue
varValue = strLocalAppDataFolder & "\"
Call WriteRegistry(strRegPath, varValue, "REG_SZ")

' Run PPT.
If objFSO.FileExists(strAppLocalPath) Then
  Call RunApp(strAppLocalPath, False)
Else
  Call ErrorHandler("The local application file:" & vbCrLf & strAppLocalPath & vbCrLF & "could not be found.")    
End If

Set objRemoteFolder = Nothing
Set objLocalFolder = Nothing
Set objLocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
Set objDesktopFolder = Nothing
Set objAppShell = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing

WScript.Quit


' Supporting subfunctions
' -----------------------

Sub RunApp(ByVal strFile, ByVal booBackground)

  Dim objShell
  Dim intWindowStyle

  ' Open as default foreground application.
  intWindowStyle = 1

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run Chr(34) & strFile & Chr(34), intWindowStyle, False
  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub KillTask(ByVal strWindowTitle)

  Dim objShell

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  objShell.Run "TaskKill.exe /FI ""WINDOWTITLE eq " & strWindowTitle & """", 7, False
  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub AwaitProcess(ByVal strProcess)

  Dim objSvc
  Dim strQuery
  Dim colProcess
  Dim intCount

  Set objSvc = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2")
  strQuery = "select * from win32_process where name='" & strProcess & "'"

  Do 
    Set colProcess = objSvc.Execquery(strQuery)
    intCount = colProcess.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
      WScript.Sleep 300
    End If
  Loop Until intCount = 0

  Set colProcess = Nothing
  Set objSvc = Nothing

End Sub


Sub WriteRegistry(ByVal strRegPath, ByVal varValue, ByVal strRegType)
  ' strRegType should be: 
  '   "REG_SZ" for a string
  '   "REG_DWORD" for an integer
  '   "REG_BINARY" for a binary or boolean
  '   "REG_EXPAND_SZ" for an expandable string

  Dim objShell

  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  Call objShell.RegWrite(strRegPath, varValue, strRegType)

  Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub


Sub ErrorHandler(Byval strMessage)

  Set objRemoteFolder = Nothing
  Set objLocalFolder = Nothing
  Set objLocalAppDataFolder = Nothing
  Set objDesktopFolder = Nothing
  Set objAppShell = Nothing
  Set objFSO = Nothing
  WScript.Echo strMessage
  WScript.Quit

End Sub
```